# Logitech G930 Headset only works in one ear

Tags: linux, usb, audio, debian-wheezy

I have a wireless USB Logitech G930 headset. It works out of the box in Debian, except that only the right channel works. The other side doesn't produce any sound. If I plug my headset into my Windows computer, both channels work just fine.

I'm kinda lost on how to debug this.

Utility I use to adjust sound:
[image: Utility I use to adjust sound]

dmesg:

```
[513775.388381] usb 3-2: new full-speed USB device number 3 using ohci_hcd
[513776.113212] usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=0a1f
[513776.113229] usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=
0
[513776.113239] usb 3-2: Product: Logitech G930 Headset
[513776.113247] usb 3-2: Manufacturer: Logitech
[513776.206686] input: Logitech Logitech G930 Headset as /devices/pci0000:00/000
0:00:12.0/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.3/input/input15
[513776.207382] generic-usb 0003:046D:0A1F.0002: input,hiddev0,hidraw0: USB HID
v1.01 Device [Logitech Logitech G930 Headset] on usb-0000:00:12.0-2/input3
```

uname:

```
Linux host 3.2.0-4-686-pae #1 SMP Debian 3.2.57-3+deb7u2 i686 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: @ali786 No, they're different computers. What do you mean by audio connector pin?

Comment: This is a USB headset. Other, non-USB headphones work fine on the same computer.

Comment: Ohh.. I didn't notice that you are using wireless headphone. Then I think problem is in drivers as you'r saying other headphones are working fine. so the settings are correct try reinstalling drivers or download latest one.